# how to search an element in a vector of strings using with and without find

Tags: c++

I am trying to find a way to search a word by using vectors but program below doesn't give required element

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ifstream input_file("test.txt");

    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> elements;
    for (int line_no = 1; std::getline(input_file, line); ++line_no)
    {
        elements.push_back(line);
    }

    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = find(elements.begin(), elements.end(), ".");
    if (it != elements.end())
        std::cout << "element found: " << (*it) << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "element not found " << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried without find like below but if fails and else gives answer like above case

```
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = elements.begin();
    for (; it != elements.end(); ++it)
    {
        if ((*it) == ".")
        {
            std::cout << "element found: " << (*it);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "element not found" << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Below is in my input file text.txt

```
This is Arif.
I work.
```

What is solution to my code, why in both approaches else block gives output not if block?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you expect to find. However, `getline` reads an entire line as a single string, and unless you have one line with just a `.` there is no match for `"."`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that `std::getline` reads that whole line at once. Both of your examples are checking that whole string and comparing it to `"."` so it's never going to match. Alternatively, if what you're trying to do is check if the entire line contains a period or not (and where) you can use the `std::string::find` like this.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ifstream input_file("test.txt");

    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> elements;
    for (int line_no = 1; std::getline(input_file, line); ++line_no)
    {
        elements.push_back(line);
    }

    std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it;
    for (it = elements.begin(); it != elements.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::string temp(*it);
        size_t found = temp.find(".");
        if (found != std::string::npos)
        {
            std::cout << "element found at position " << found << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "element not found " << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```